# R get regression line from matrix

Tags: r

I have to use R to get the regression line in the format  `y = a + b * x` and then in `x = a + b * y` with the help of R.
Given is the following matrix:

```
A2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4   -2
[2,]    8   -3
[3,]    6    1
[4,]    2    2
[5,]   -1    1
```

How does htis work? or can I display a graph where I can read the equation from?

Comment: lm(A2[,2] ~ A2[,1]) ??? I don't quite get your question. It will print an intercept and coefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want to regress A[,2] (y) against A[,1] (x)

1. List item

   A2=cbind(c(4,8,6,2,-1),c(-2,-3,1,2,1))

You can look at the model:

```
lm(A2[,2] ~ A2[,1])

Call:
lm(formula = A2[, 2] ~ A2[, 1])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      A2[, 1]  
     1.2951      -0.3934
```

This means A2[,2] = 1.2951 - 0.3934*A[,1]. To plot do:

```
plot(A2)
abline(lm(A2[,2] ~ A2[,1]))
```

Comment: Thanks you helped me a lot!